# template functions, how to send different structures and create a if/else statement based on type?

Tags: c++, templates

i'm trying to build a general purpose template function which should function with 2 different type of structure i'll write an example

```
struct sa {
int a;
int b;
char d;
}
struct sb {
int a;
int b;
int c;
}

template < class T>
void f_print(T & s_passed, bool s_typeB){
std::cout << s_passed.a << endl ;
std::cout << s_passed.b << endl ;
if(s_typeB == false){
std::cout << s_passed.d << endl ;
}else{
std::cout << s_passed.c << endl ;
}
}
```

then in main:

```
{
struct  sa str_TEST_A ;
struct  sb str_TEST_B ;

f_print(str_TEST_A,false);
f_print(str_TEST_B,true);
}
```

now , this is a short example of my issue where i'm handling much more complicated structures, anyway what i get is
error: 'struct sa' has no member named 'd'

the problem is that the gnu c++ compiler didn't recognize that not all operations in the function are execute when struct sa is passed, and d is printed only when sb is passed,
how i can fix this without creating a duplicated function 1 for each structure type?

thank you :)
Francesco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could move the specialized parts in separate functions and call these from your generic template:

```
void f_print_special(sa & s_passed) {
   std::cout << s_passed.d << endl ;
}

void f_print_special(sb & s_passed) {
   std::cout << s_passed.c << endl ;
}

template <class T>
void f_print(T & s_passed) {
   std::cout << s_passed.a << endl ;
   std::cout << s_passed.b << endl ;
   f_print_special(s_passed);
}
```

Comment: You have both functions with `sa&`

Comment: thank you this is not bad, maybe i can arrange something like this for some functions and for others i'll have to duplicate ;) Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

sth has the correct answer.  However, if you need a more generic solution, in that say the function that accepts sb type could accept any type that implements the concept "has C" (or whatever) then you need to use *tag based dispatch*.  I'd suggest looking it up because though I might be able to describe one hypothetical situation that may or may not resemble your real problem, I couldn't get them all.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just g++.  That's invalid C++.  Every statement in a function (template or not) must be valid, even if you can "prove" it's not executed.

What's so bad about giving them separate functions?  Of course, you can deal with some common subparts by calling another subfunction.

If you want the functions to have the same name, go ahead and do that.  Function overloading will handle it.

Comment: thank you i know that ;) i just wondering if there was some way of doind that that i don't know mmm maybe i can do something better using derivated structures where sa and sb both come from another struct ? i'll take a deep look into this...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is just a test case for you in writing templates but a more natural implementation would be to have `sa` and `sb` inherit from a common base struct `sbase` say, with members `a` and `b` only, and then have `sa` and `sb` implement their own `operator<<`, delegating to the base `operator<<` for the common parts.